# Bundled product on configurable product page

Tags: magento-1.7, template, layout

So, on Product Detail Page of `configurable product`, I need to show some `bundle` product with options, button to buy,  and so on.

Now on this page I have an object of bundled product. The question: is there are any method to show this product with all I need?

My idea , looking at layout `bundle.xml` is to implement all in `PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle` node, but I think there are another ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please explain in more detail. If you want to show a bundle product you have a lot of work, because Magento relies on Mage::registry('current_product').

Why you can try is, to copy everything from `catalog_product_view` layout handle and all of the bundle stuff, load the bundle product, change the registry and then render all the blocks, after this, you change it back to you configurable product.

Might work...

Comment: On configurable product page I nee dto show boundle product. So in <PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable> node I need to set block which needed for bundle product. Am I right? But I stack on this.

Comment: Yes you are right. But the problem as I described above is, that the logic in the blocks depends highly in the magento registry, so you will have a lot of fun.

Comment: Yes, now I'm really have a party with this!) Have you see some examples of it?

Comment: Not that I know of. Showing simple products, yes but bundles - no.